# Using Eigen matrices with a custom type

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a type of numbers named `lazyScalar` and I want, using **Eigen**, to deal with matrices of such numbers. Arithmetic operators are not defined for these numbers, so I defined them, e.g. the multiplication:

```cpp
lazyScalar operator*=(const lazyScalar x, const lazyScalar other) {
  ......
}

lazyScalar operator*(const lazyScalar lhs, const lazyScalar rhs) {
  ......
}
```

But the compilation of my code fails, with the message:

```
no match for 'operator*'
```

Why my multiplication is not found? Isn't it possible to deal with matrices in **Eigen** once we have defined the arithmetic operators for the entries?

Comment: Maybe related: the expected form of [`operator*=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) would be `lazyScalar& operator*=(lazyScalar& self, const lazyScalar & other)`, and of [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) would be `lazyScalar operator*(const lazyScalar & lhs, const lazyScalar & rhs)`, note the references

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thanks to [this link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html).

```cpp
namespace Eigen {

template<> struct NumTraits<lazyScalar> : GenericNumTraits<lazyScalar>
{
  typedef lazyScalar Real;
  typedef lazyScalar NonInteger;
  typedef lazyScalar Nested;
  
  enum {
    IsComplex = 0,
    IsInteger = 0,
    IsSigned = 1,
    RequireInitialization = 1,
    ReadCost = 1,
    AddCost = 3,
    MulCost = 3
  };
};

}

namespace std {

  // definitions of operators go here

}
```

I also had to define `max`, `min` and `abs`.

Not sure this is the better way though.

Comment: you shouldn't be putting anything in `namespace std`

Comment: If that's the approach suggested by Eigen's doc itself, then that's the correct way to do it and there is no better one. However, as @Caleth says, you should avoid putting anything in `namespace std`, the link you mentioned explicitly says it works but it's not recommended. Quoting: _The math function should be defined in the same namespace than T, or in the std namespace though that second approach is not recommended._